# Old C++ programmer, Java newbie, needs help about Swing JFrames in packages

Tags: java, swing, package

I'm building a package that i plan to re-use in a lot of application.
This package contains a "serial port manager": whatever application i'll build, i'll always need to set the comm port and the related parameters.

There's a way to have a JFrame (or a whole form?), with all the needed code, inside the package, so whenever an application needs to setup a port it calls a method in the package, and a modal form will appears?

...i hope to have been clear....

Comment: Sure, it's possible. How can we help you?

Comment: So whats the challenge you are facing ? You need help with creating package or building swing GUI ?

Comment: Putting a dependency on Swing from your comms package (a general purpose library of some sort?) sounds like a bad idea. I'd suggest it should be the other way around if anything.

Comment: I agree with Ash! 
Rather just provide public methods and take required parameters.

Comment: Ok, trying to explain me better.
Let my CommManager Package have a SerialManager class.
SerialManager have a public method called "showSerialSettings".
This metod should always open a modal form with all the control needed to set the Serial Port. All the code, the "form" (whatever it will be) stay inside the CommPackage.
...continue...

Comment: ....
So, no matter what program i'm developing, when i import the Package i just have to add a call to the showSerialSettings() to open the setting form. (now, the Serial Port is an example: my real package will handle a lot more of settings, that's why i'd like to make it all working and enclosed in the package).

So, i think i could refine my question in 2 parts:
1) What kind of container should i use to build the "face" of the modal form?
2) How can i, then, make it working in a generic app importing my package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI example:

```
public class PortConfiguration extends JDialog() {
    private int baudrate;
    private String moreStuff;

    //show window, events and more
    public PortConfiguration() {
        super(null,true);
        this.setVisible( false );
        //GUI creation...
    }

    //get configuration:
    public int getBaudrate() {}
    public String getStuff() {}
}
```

Port implementation:

```
public class Port {
    public Port( int baudrate, String stuff ) {
        //create, open port...
    }
}
```

And then you can use them when needed:

```
PortConfiguration portGUI = new PortConfiguration();
portGUI.setVisible( true );
Port p = new Port( portGUI.getBaudrate(), portGUI.getStuff() );
```

About packages:
You can create a main package (`serialport`) with a 'subpackage' `dialog` inside for the GUI class.
The `Port` class would be inside the main package `serialport`

Answer (score 1):

This would be better suited to a modal *component* such as a [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) or a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).  Both will 'block' in the sense I suspect you mean.

See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
public class SerialPortManagerFrame extends JFrame
{
    private final JTextField baudRateTextField;
    // More controls here

    public SerialPortManagerFrame (int baudRate /* Other parameters here */)
    {
        super ("Serial Port Manager");

        baudRateTextField.setText (String.valueOf (baudRate));
        // Initialize other fields here

        getContentPane.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        getContentPane.add (baudRateTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // Other GUI initialization here including
    }

    public int getBaudRate ()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt (baudRateTextField.getText ());
    }

    // Other methods here
}
```